# Truth value of quantified statement

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I have $P(x,y) \iff xy=1$; the universe of discourse for $x$ is the set of positive integers, and the universe of discourse for $y$ is the set of real numbers.
$$
\forall x \exists y P(x,y)
$$

I'm confused about reading the above statement. I'm quoting above statement from a book that says the statement read as "For every positive integer $x$ there is a real number $y$" such that $xy=1$. so the statement is true...I want to know what value, that makes this statement true, of $y$. is there only one value of $y$ for all values of $x$? or I need to change the value of $y$ every time when i change $x$.

Please If someone could explain it would be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$\forall x \in \mathbb Z^+,  \exists y \in \mathbb R$ such that $xy = 1.$  True. The value of y that makes the statement true will change according to the value of $x$:  $(x, y): (2, \frac12), (8, \frac 18), ...$.  we can take any integer $x$, and put $y = \frac 1x$ so that  $xy = 1$ is true. In truth, we can say that every positive integer has a multiplicative inverse, y,  in  $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb R$

The expression $\exists y \forall x, P(x, y)$ is false when $P(x, y)$ means $xy = 1$. That is, there does not exist a value of $y \in \mathbb R,$ such that for each and every positive integer , we have that $xy=1$.

Comment: Thanks amWhy...I understood first statement...In second statment you read y only one time then loop through all values of x?

Comment: Yes, indeed. There is one single y, and when we loop through values of x, we will soon realized that most, if not all, do **not** satisfy $xy = 1$

Comment: re, my last comment: Suppose $y = \pi \in \mathbb R$. Is every integer, x, satisfy the claim that $x\cdot \pi = 1$? No INTEGER x is such that $x=\frac 1\pi.$

Comment: You're welcome, @zuby!

Comment: Please amWhy explain this statement also how to read?...I'm reading this statement like: first value of x for all value of y then x's 2nd value again for all value of y. is this right?

∀x∀yP(x,y)

Comment: This means that for each and every value of $x$ (in the universe of discourse), every $y$ is such that $P(x, y)$ is true.  I think I get what your saying: Yes.

Comment: Thank you amWhy for your quick response 

In paper I'm writing like this.

 ∀x∀yP(x,y) = 2x+y=xy

2(1)+0 = 2 and multiple of 1x0 = 0
2(1)+1 = 3 and multiple of 1x1 = 1
2(1)+2 = 4 and multiple of 1x2 = 2

Is there any easy method to calculate truth value?